# Can I state $f(1_{15})=48_{20}$? When $f(4_{15})=12_{20}$?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_{15}\to\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ be a homomorphism such that $f(4_{15})=12_{20}$. Show $f(1_{15})$.

I answered the question by noticing that the group is cyclic of order $15$, so $1_{15}=16_{15}$. Therefore $f((4_{15})^4)=f(4_{15})^4=(12_{20})^4=48_{20}$.

**Question:**

1)Can I state $f(1_{15})=48_{20}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It'd be better if you stated $f(1_{15}) = 8_{20}$, wouldn't it?

Comment: @fleablood                 Why not $4_{20}$? Since  $48_{20}=\frac{20}{gcd(20,48)}=5$ so $4_{20}$ would be the smallest equality with the same order of $48_{20}$. Still I am not sure it equals $f(1_{15})$.

Comment: What?  $48_{20} \ne \frac {20}{\gcd(20,48)}$?  $48_{20}\equiv 48\mod 20 \equiv 8 \mod 20$.  $|48_20| = \frac {20}{\gcd(20,48)}=5$ but $|4| = |8|=12|=|16| = 5$.  Why would it be the *smallest* number with order $5$?

Comment: @fleablood Why would it be $8$ instead of $4$? That is what I am not understanding.

Comment: Because $48 = 8 + 2*20$.  $48 \ne 4 + 20k$.   $x_b = \{n| n = b \pm k*b\}$.  And $48$ does *NOT* equal $4 \pm 20k$.

Comment: $a \equiv b \mod n$ means $a-b$ is divisible by $n$.  ANd $48-4 = 44$ is not divisible by $20$ so $48 \not \equiv 4 \mod 20$.  $a\equiv b \mod n$ means $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.  $48$ has remainder $8$ and and $4$ has remainder $4$.  Those are not equal.

Comment: Remember this is "circular math".  As soon as you get to $20$ you repeat back.  $18_{20}= 18_{20}; 19_{20}=19_{20}; 20_{20} = 0_{20}; 21_{20} = 1_{20}; 22_{20} = 2_{20}; ...... 39_{20} = 19_{20}; 40_{20} = 0_{20}; 41_{20}= 1_{20}$.   This is very weird to me.  You remember and understand something fairly complicated and sophisticated but seem utterly ignorant in something very basic and trivial.

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $[48]=[8]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$

Comment: Is it not $4_{20}$?

Comment: Why would it be $4_{20}$?  $48 = 2*20 + 8$.

Comment: @fleablood $8$ would have the same order $5$.

Comment: So?  $4, 8,12,$ and $16$ all have order $5$.  Order $5$ is not unique.

Comment: Back to definition.  $x_b = \{n\in \mathbb Z|n = x + k*b; k \in \mathbb Z\}$.  So $48_{20} = \{n\in \mathbb Z|n = 48 + 20k\}$.  As $n = 48 + k*(20) \iff n = 8+(k-2)*20$ we have $48_{20} = 8_{20}$.  As $4\ne 48 + 20k$ and if $n = 4+20*k$ the $n\ne 48 + 20m$ so $4_{20} \ne 8_{20}$.  This is *VERY* basic.